# Map tasks keep Running even after the node is killed on Apache Yarn

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I'm on Apache2.6.0 YARN and I'm trying to test the dynamic addition and removal of nodes from the Cluster.

The test starts a Job with 2 nodes and while the Job is progressing, It removes one of the node* by killing the dataNode and NodeManager Daemons.( is it ok to remove a node like this? )

*this node is not running ResourceManager/ApplicationMaster for sure.

After the node is successfully removed( I can confirm this from resource manager logs- attached) the test adds it back and waits till the job completes.

Node Removal Logs:

```
2015-08-14 11:15:56,902 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.AbstractLivelinessMonitor: Expired:host172:36158 Timed out after 60 secs
2015-08-14 11:15:56,903 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeImpl: Deactivating Node host172:36158 as it is now LOST
2015-08-14 11:15:56,904 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeImpl: host172:36158 Node Transitioned from RUNNING to LOST
2015-08-14 11:15:56,905 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1439575616861_0001_01_000006 Container Transitioned from RUNNING to KILLED
2015-08-14 11:15:56,906 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.common.fica.FiCaSchedulerApp: Completed container: container_1439575616861_0001_01_000006 in state: KILLED event:KILL
2015-08-14 11:15:56,906 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=hadoop   OPERATION=AM Released Container TARGET=SchedulerApp     RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1439575616861_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1439575616861_0001_01_000006
2015-08-14 11:15:56,906 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerNode: Released container container_1439575616861_0001_01_000006 of capacity <memory:1024, vCores:1> on host host172:36158, which currently has 1 containers, <memory:1024, vCores:1> used and <memory:1024, vCores:7> available, release resources=true
2015-08-14 11:15:56,906 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: default used=<memory:3584, vCores:3> numContainers=3 user=hadoop user-resources=<memory:3584, vCores:3>
2015-08-14 11:15:56,906 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: completedContainer container=Container: [ContainerId: container_1439575616861_0001_01_000006, NodeId: host172:36158, NodeHttpAddress: host172:8042, Resource: <memory:1024, vCores:1>, Priority: 20, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: XX.XX.0.2:36158 }, ] queue=default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:3584, vCores:3>, usedCapacity=1.75, absoluteUsedCapacity=1.75, numApps=1, numContainers=3 cluster=<memory:2048, vCores:8>
2015-08-14 11:15:56,906 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: completedContainer queue=root usedCapacity=1.75 absoluteUsedCapacity=1.75 used=<memory:3584, vCores:3> cluster=<memory:2048, vCores:8>
2015-08-14 11:15:56,906 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: Re-sorting completed queue: root.default stats: default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:3584, vCores:3>, usedCapacity=1.75, absoluteUsedCapacity=1.75, numApps=1, numContainers=3
2015-08-14 11:15:56,906 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Application attempt appattempt_1439575616861_0001_000001 released container container_1439575616861_0001_01_000006 on node: host: host172:36158 #containers=1 available=1024 used=1024 with event: KILL
2015-08-14 11:15:56,907 INFO   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1439575616861_0001_01_000005 Container Transitioned from RUNNING to KILLED
2015-08-14 11:15:56,907 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.common.fica.FiCaSchedulerApp: Completed container: container_1439575616861_0001_01_000005 in state: KILLED event:KILL
2015-08-14 11:15:56,907 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=hadoop   OPERATION=AM Released Container TARGET=SchedulerApp     RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1439575616861_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1439575616861_0001_01_000005
2015-08-14 11:15:56,907 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerNode: Released container container_1439575616861_0001_01_000005 of capacity <memory:1024, vCores:1> on host host172:36158, which currently has 0 containers, <memory:0, vCores:0> used and <memory:2048, vCores:8> available, release resources=true
2015-08-14 11:15:56,907 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: default used=<memory:2560, vCores:2> numContainers=2 user=hadoop user-resources=<memory:2560, vCores:2>
2015-08-14 11:15:56,907 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: completedContainer container=Container: [ContainerId: container_1439575616861_0001_01_000005, NodeId: host172:36158, NodeHttpAddress: host172:8042, Resource: <memory:1024, vCores:1>, Priority: 20, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: XX.XX.0.2:36158 }, ] queue=default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:2560, vCores:2>, usedCapacity=1.25, absoluteUsedCapacity=1.25, numApps=1, numContainers=2 cluster=<memory:2048, vCores:8>
2015-08-14 11:15:56,907 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: completedContainer queue=root usedCapacity=1.25 absoluteUsedCapacity=1.25 used=<memory:2560, vCores:2> cluster=<memory:2048, vCores:8>
2015-08-14 11:15:56,907 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: Re-sorting completed queue: root.default stats: default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:2560, vCores:2>, usedCapacity=1.25, absoluteUsedCapacity=1.25, numApps=1, numContainers=2
2015-08-14 11:15:56,907 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Application attempt appattempt_1439575616861_0001_000001 released container container_1439575616861_0001_01_000005 on node: host: host172:36158 #containers=0 available=2048 used=0 with event: KILL
2015-08-14 11:15:56,907 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Removed node host172:36158 clusterResource: <memory:2048, vCores:8>
```

Node Addition logs:

```
2015-08-14 11:19:43,529 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.RackResolver: Resolved host172 to /default-rack
2015-08-14 11:19:43,530 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceTrackerService: NodeManager from node host172(cmPort: 59426 httpPort: 8042) registered with capability: <memory:2048, vCores:8>, assigned nodeId host172:59426
2015-08-14 11:19:43,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeImpl: host172:59426 Node Transitioned from NEW to RUNNING
2015-08-14 11:19:43,535 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Added node host172:59426 clusterResource: <memory:4096, vCores:16>
```

Here's the problem:

The Job never completes! 
According to the logs the mapTasks which were scheduled on the node that was removed are still "RUNNING" with a mapProgress of 100%. These tasks stays in the same state forever.

In the AppMasterContainer logs I see that it continuously tries to  connect to the previous node host172/XX.XX.XX.XX:36158 though it was removed and added on a different port host172/XX.XX.XX.XX:59426

```
......
......
2015-08-14 11:25:21,662 INFO [ContainerLauncher #7] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: host172/XX.XX.XX.XX:36158. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
......
......
```

P.S: The Jobs completes normally without dynamic addition and removal of nodes on the same Cluster with same memory settings.

Comment: Looks like the App master tries to connect to the Node that was removed for 30Min before it gives up on that. Is there a way I can reduce this wait?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like symptoms of YARN bug on 2.6.0.

After you remove the node, ideally, the AppMaster retries to connect to the nodemanager before eventually failing with NoRouteToHostException's and killing containers launched in that node and marking them as failed.

However, with that bug, Connection timeouts from AppMaster to nodemanagers are retried at multiple levels causing the job appear stuck although all the containers are successful.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-3238

This is fixed in 2.7.0 hadoop versions.